# mvn clean install Ubuntu terminal

Tags: spring-boot, maven-3

If i run mvn clean install I get the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/inject/Module
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.container(MavenCli.java:636)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:282)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:193)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
```

If I use the InteliJ Ui, it compiles.
I used a different terminal.

any suggestions, please

Comment: Are you running on plain command line (not within IntelliJ Terminal)... which version of Maven do you use? Which JDK are you using? Please give the information what `mvn --version` prints out...

Comment: I have uninstalled mvn and jdk.
Now I get 
```The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program
NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE
```

My java path in .bashrc is 
```

Comment: my java paths is
```export JAVA_HOME=usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

Comment: Apache Maven 3.6.3
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 11.0.11, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-11.0.11

Comment: If this is the output of `mvn --version` because a usual output looks like this: `Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)` which contains the hash. That means you are using not the original Apache Maven version. Please deinstall the version you installed via OS and download Maven from Maven site https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi and retest this. The OS has repacked Maven and used different versions of libraries which can cause such issues which I fear is the cause of that issue...